# How does やがる work with なる?

Tags: translation, verbs

"もう1ヶ月が経ってんだぞ！?"
"一人でしたって変な感じになりやがるし"

The character friend has not been playing with him for a month. From context I can gather that "Even if I try to do things alone, it feels weird!" However, I don't get why is やがる being used here? Is not "I feel weird" something automatic? It's not something the other person is doing since they have not talked for a month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb やがる follows another verb and typically indicates disdain for the doer. However, sometimes it attaches to a verb that has no particular doer like in your case, and then it simply adds speaker's unpleasantness/irritation for the situation